# SQL: How to select all rows, where row 1 and 2 equals one of 5 names from the statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with around 100 medicine interactions. I'm trying to make a statement where I insert X amount of drug names and it returns all rows where those drug names present in the first two columns.

If a patient has dicoumarol, warfarin and reserpine, it would return row 4 and 6 in the "Example of the table" picture below.

Example of the table: [image: https://i.imgur.com/o6Nv39I.jpg]

I use phpMyAdmin, which uses MySQL. I've tried a bunch of standard `SELECT` queries with a `WHERE` that says *MedikamentA* and *MedikamentB* equals the name of two drugs like:

```
SELECT * FROM MIdatabase 
WHERE MedikamentA = 'dicoumarol' 
  AND MedikamentB = 'ergotamine' " OR " MedikmentA = 'ergotamine' 
   OR MedikamentB = 'dicoumarol'
```

Not completely correct, but I wrote it top of my head. Probably need to switch an `OR` around and have some paranthesis.

I'm close to ripping a bit of hair off the top of my head trying to do this :p

Comment: "*So, if a patient has both "Warfarin" and "Dicoumarol" but not Epinephrine, it would return the bottom row.*", I am not sure to understand. Which row exactly?

Comment: @KévinBibollet
A nice admin helped format it, since I didn't have enough reputation, but it accidentally reverted my own edit :)

I re-edited the post, so it should make more sense and use the picture I uploaded. If you look at the picture, I want it to return row 4 and 6 for a patient with dicoumarol, warfarin and reserpine.

And I want to be able to add a new name to the SQL query, so that it finds the new combinations that might arise, like if I added rescinnamine later on, it should also get row 5.

Comment: I think I understand. Can you provide us what you already tried?

Comment: @KévinBibollet
I've tried only those queries that are something along the line of
" SELECT * FROM MIdatabase WHERE MedikamentA = 'dicoumarol' AND MedikamentB = 'ergotamine' " OR " MedikmentA = 'ergotamine' OR MedikamentB = 'dicoumarol', but that just returns one single interaction.

The problem is getting it to work with a list of names I enter. I can do the Java part and put variables into the SQL statements, but... Just not sure what the statement should actually look like.
Here's a part of my Java code: https://prnt.sc/nofmbd

Comment: Please add your query winthin your post, and the others will have all needed information directly.

Comment: What if a row contains the same medicine, say "dicoumarol", in both columns. Should it be included or not? Or will that never happen?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The table contains no duplicates of a name in both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query doesn't give you what you are expecting because it is missing parenthesis.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MIdatabase
WHERE
  MedikamentA IN ('dicoumarol', 'warfarin', 'reserpine')
  AND MedikamentB IN ('dicoumarol', 'warfarin', 'reserpine');
```

The above query is the same as the one below:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MIdatabase
WHERE
  (
    MedikamentA = 'dicoumarol'
    OR MedikamentA = 'warfarin'
    OR MedikamentA = 'reserpine'
  )
  AND (
    MedikamentB = 'dicoumarol'
    OR MedikamentB = 'warfarin'
    OR MedikamentB = 'reserpine'
  );
```

Comment: The first one is perfect for me, because I can make a few line of codes in Java where I fetch the names of all drugs on the list and insert them into one big string, which will be inserted in those two places. The second one will be a lot more bothersome.

This is fantastic! Thanks!
Am I supposed to "Accept" other answers that also works, even if this one is the most useful for me?

Comment: You can only accept one answer by question. However you can upvote the other answers to thank their author!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MIdatabase 
WHERE 'dicoumarol' IN ( MedikamentA, MedikamentB )
  AND 'ergotamine' IN ( MedikamentA, MedikamentB )
```

Comment: Does this type of SQL really work? I have never seen the reverse of the `IN` like this. Let me check.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score -1):

You will need multiple LIKE statements along with the OR statement to meet the conditional requirements of calling for multiple drugs for each column. The second part of the LIKE statements needs AND as you will be referring to a separate column as part of the conditional statement.

```
select * from table where MedikamentA like 'dicoumarol' or MedikamentA like 'warfarin' or MedikamentA like 'reserpine' and MedikamentB like 'dicoumarol' or MedikamentB like 'warfarin' or MedikamentB like 'reserpine';
```

Comment: Why use `LIKE` without wildcards? Might as well use equality `=`.

Comment: And you also need to learn how to use parentheses together with logical operators.